# How do I identify the display item style name in the Fonts & Colors Environment setting in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, razor

Which setting determines the style for the Razor view engine code in HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default setting for Razor highlighting is Yellow; you can change that in settings or you can download a new theme: http://studiostyl.es/

Comment: True. Thanks. But *which* setting is it in the dialog box?

Comment: You mean options -> font and colors? Preprocessor Keyword is the color of the wrapper around Razor code. for example @ and @{}. And then Razor Code which is right below it is the setting for actual code inside it.

Comment: Ha! Thanks. Never seen it before. Didn't realise it had been added! :)